# How do I get rid of pictures in an array?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a simple game for my programming class and I'm trying to spawn enemies in using an array. When I go to shoot the enemy, it kills the last enemy that has spawned in the array rather than the one I shot at. I set the array to an unlimited value so that i can spawn as many enemies as i want. So for example: If I spawned in 3 enemies, it would go through the first and second enemy and kill the third one. I understand why this is happening but i just don't know how to fix it so that it kills the enemy i shoot at.

If extra information is needed just say so in the comments

```
Private Sub bullet_movement_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bullet_movement.Tick    
Dim B As Integer
    For B = 0 To BulletNumberLeft
        Bullet_arrayLeft(B).Left -= 10
        If Bullet_arrayLeft(B).Bounds.IntersectsWith(Left_boundary.Bounds) Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(Bullet_arrayLeft(B))
        End If
        If enemycount >= 0 Then
            If Bullet_arrayLeft(B).Bounds.IntersectsWith(Enemyarray(enemycount).Bounds) Then
                Me.Controls.Remove(Bullet_arrayLeft(B))
                Me.Controls.Remove(Enemyarray(enemycount))
                enemycount = enemycount - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You do everything with Enemyarray(enemycount), you need a second for loop that looks if the bullet intersect with any of the enemy in the list.

Comment: You can only declare the kill after you looped through them all, finding the closest one.

Comment: I don’t have a way to loop through all of them because there is no name assigned to them. It has an unlimited amount of spawns. There is no list of enemy names.